# Why is this not an open set in this topology? I don't get it

Tags: general-topology

A non-English textbook I am reading and here's an example I don't understand.

> Consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Define $U_a=\{x \in \mathbb{R}|a<x\}$ for some real $a$.Therefore, $U_a$ is the set of real numbers that are greater than $a$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then define the set $\tau=\{U_a\}_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \cup \{\phi, \mathbb{R}\}$. This is a set defined by the subset $U_a$, the empty set $\phi$ and the entire set $\mathbb{R}$ itself. It is easily verified that $\tau$ is a topology.
>
> (Okay so far)
>
> Thus $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ can be seen as a topological space. In this space, the open interval  $(a,b)$ is NOT in $\tau$ so bizarrely, it cannot been considered as an "open set."

Wait, $(a,b) \not\in \tau$? Why? Clearly it must be.
For whatever $a$, $U_a$ is the set of reals greater than $a$. and $\tau$ is a UNION of this and $\mathbb{R}$ itself(in fact, with any set $\Lambda \cup \phi=\Lambda$ so I don't see what the point is for having the empty set there. It's like $a+0=0$, it doesn't do anything), so $\tau$ is $\mathbb{R}$ itself, no?

The definition of $\tau$ is basically saying that it's the entire set, no? I am so confused. Any subset union-ed with the entire set would surely produce the entire set. Again, union-ing that with $\phi$ shouldn't matter since it's empty and doesn't add nor subtract anything from the set.

What is going on? Does anyone have an explanation for this? I am very baffled.

Comment: $\tau$ (the topology) is a *collection* of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $(a,b)$ has not been mentioned, it is not a member of $\tau$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\tau$ is a collection of **sets of reals**, not of individual reals (so when you write "$\tau$ is $\mathbb{R}$ itself," you're making a type error). So in this example, $\tau$ is the collection of sets of the form $(a, \infty)$, together with $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$.

Is $(1, 3)$ in $\tau$? Well, there are three possible ways to be in $\tau$:

- $(1, 3)=\mathbb{R}$: clearly false.
- $(1, 3)=\emptyset$: clearly false.
- $(1, 3)=(a,\infty)$ for some $a$: false again! Any set of the form $(a, \infty)$ will contain an element bigger than $3$ (for instance), but $(1, 3)$ doesn't contain any element bigger than $3$.

So $(1, 3)$ is not a set in the collection $\tau$.

---

Side note: When we say $\tau$ is a topology, we mean that, as a collection of sets, $\tau$ is closed under certain operations (arbitrary unions, finite intersections), and contains the whole space $\mathbb{R}$ and the emptyset $\emptyset$. It takes a bit of thought to show that the $\tau$ defined above does indeed have these properties, but it does. HINT: let's say I have a bunch of reals $a_i$ ($i\in I$). What can I say about the set $$\bigcup_{i\in I} (a_i, \infty)?$$